# wmic hangs in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, wmi

If I open Cygwin in rxvt, running `wmic` does not show the expected `wmic:root\cli>` prompt.  If I execute `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe` from `cmd.exe`, running `wmic` inside `bash.exe` returns the expected prompt.  Why?

I have the environment variable `CYGWIN` set to `ntsec tty`.  I can `echo "hello"` with a response and everything else seems happy.  It's just when I run wmic and a few other Windows applications that have a prompt, the prompt never appears.

Answer (score 6):

For wmic, try using `echo '' | wmic <query here>`, where `<query here>` is your desired query.

For instance, to get a Dell machine's service tag over SSH: `echo '' | wmic bios get serialnumber`.

Getting interactive mode to work seems fruitless to me, but this should expose most of wmic's functionality to you.

**Failed Attempts:**

One alternative solution I read was to use `< /dev/null` at the end instead of an `echo '' |` in the front, i.e.: `wmic bios get serialnumber < /dev/null`.  I am not, however, having luck with this one. (from [Nabble thread](http://old.nabble.com/WMIC-td23502632.html))

Another alternative solution I read was to attempt to set `tty` in the `CYGWIN` environmental variable.  That had no luck for me, either.  (from a Larry Hall posting on the Cygwin mailing list, not linked due to spam prevention)

Answer (score 2):

It's ye olde Cygwin pty vs native console app issue. Rxvt is based on a "pseudo terminal device" (pty), which Cygwin implements using Windows pipes. Non-Cygwin apps only see the Windows pipes though, which makes some of them think that they should enter non-interactive mode without a prompt. (More specifically, the isatty() function returns false when invoked on a pipe.)

Comment: So, any idea on how to fix it?  I'm I stuck using cmd.exe for certain things?

Comment: Some programs have an option to explicitly tell them to enter interactive mode, e.g. 'python -i', so check whether wmic has one of those. Otherwise, console.sf.net puts a nicer interface on the Windows console.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Cygwin  you are using, you may have to leverage the < /dev/null.  I believe I am using 1.7 and I no longer must use < /dev/null on most versions of Windows (the exception is Windows 2003 R2, you still must use < /dev/null.)

Here is an example:

wmic bios (works on almost all versions of Windows)
wmic bios < /dev/null (works on all versions of Windows based on my testing)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

echo not required.

Run in cygnin prompt:

```
Administrator@darwin-test7-wi ~
$ wmic pagefileset where 'name="C:\\pagefile.sys"' delete
Deleting instance \\DARWIN-TEST7-WI\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_PageFileSetting.Name="C:\\pagefile.sys"

Instance deletion successful.
=============================================

Administrator@darwin-test7-wi ~
$ wmic pagefileset create name="C:\\pagefile.sys"

Instance creation successful.
-----------------------------------------------------

Administrator@darwin-test7-wi ~
$ wmic pagefileset where 'name="C:\\pagefile.sys"' set InitialSize=512,MaximumSize=512

Updating property(s) of '\\DARWIN-TEST7-WI\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_PageFileSetting.Name="C:\\pagefile.sys"'

Property(s) update successful.
------------------------------------------------------
```